# Proper crawler architecture - how to using ElasticSearch ecosystem?

Tags: elasticsearch, rss, logstash

In a v1.0 of a .Net data crawler, I created a Windows service that would read URLs from a database and based on some logic would select what to crawl on a specified interval.

This was single-threaded and worked well for a low number of endpoints, but scaling is obviously an issue.

I'm trying to find out how to do this using the ElasticSearch (ELK) stack and came across [HTTPBeat](https://github.com/christiangalsterer/httpbeat/releases/tag/1.0.1),

> a Beat to poll HTTP endpoints in a regular interval and ship the
>   result to the configured output channel, e.g. Logstash and
>   Elasticsearch.

In looking at the documentation, you have to add URLs to the config.yaml file.  Not what I'm looking for as the list of URLs could change and we may not want all URLs crawled at the same time.

Then there's [RSS for Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.4/plugins-inputs-rss.html), which is a command-line tool - again, not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to make use of the Beats daemon to read from the ElasticSearch database to do work based on database values - crawls, etc?

To take this to the enterprise level, do Beats or any other component of the ElasticSearch ecosystem use message queuing or a spooler (like [FileBeats](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) does - is this built into Beats?)?

Comment: Logstash can read from message queues (ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, Kafka, etc). Logstash can also repeatedly read your URL database table (using the `jdbc` input)  and then you can hit the URLs that you have retrieve using the `http` output.

Comment: Logstash can also write to messages queues (RabbitMQ, Kafka...).